# Pandas appy alternative

Tags: python

I am looking to use option #2 to get the result of option #1.

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame(np.arange(50), columns=['A'])

def test(x):
  v=30
  if v>x:
    return(x)

#option 1
df['A'].apply(lambda x: test(x))

#option 2
test(df['A'])
```

Comment: Please explain what the issue is. It isn't clear what you expect to happen with your second function. What is the condition `v>a` supposed to mean?

Comment: I would like to compare values of the array passed into the function with the keys of the dict. I.e. is the dict value v greater than a number passed to myfunc_2 as a. I would like to understand why myfunc_2 is throwing a value error.

Comment: Do you want to check for a specific value against a column in a dataframe? If so, a simple df condition would do. Wouldn't it?  df['a'].str.contains(str(v)) ?

Comment: Or you can do df.loc[df['a'] < v, 'check'] = True

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message that I get when I run your code says:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all().
```

The problem is that `a` is an array and `v` a single value, so there is no single truth value in the comparison. If you intention is to check if `v` is greater than all numbers in `a`, use `np.all(v>a)`. If you want to check if `v` is greater than just some use `np.any(v>a)`.

**On Edit**

You have now edited your question so much that it is now a new question. The entire point of the `apply` method is that if `f` is a Python function and `v` is a numpy array, then `f(v)` is probably *not* the array that you would get by applying `f` to the elements of `v`. Python is not a language that directly supports vectorized calculations. The reason that it *sometimes* seems that computations in numpy or pandas are as easy to vectorize as similar calculations in e.g. R is because of the way Python's duck-typing works. If a class defines the [magic method](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/python/magic-methods-in-python) `__add__` then you can use `+` to add elements of that class to each other in any way that you want. This is exactly what the people who created numpy have done (as well as other magic methods for things like `*,/,<` etc.) So, if a function definition is something like `def f(x): return x*x + 2*x + 3` where all the computational steps correspond to magic methods, then `v.apply(f)` and `f(v)` will work the same. Your `test` function uses the keyword `if`. There is *not* a magic method which can convert that part of the core language into something else.

Comment: Thank you for your thorough response. I think I'll need to rephrase the question.